# Instagram API - Multiple hashtags

Tags: instagram-api

Is is possible to search for Instagram post with multiple hashtags? I wanna fetch images based on multiple hashtags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the current (version 1) of [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/), it is not possible to query for multiple hash tags.

There are websites offering search for two or multiple has tags but  they are probably running two or more different searches and combining the results.

Comment: For example, one of such sites is http://mixagram.com/.

Comment: And yes they are slow like hell, for this very reason.  Having this problem right as we speak.

Comment: its actually not terrible but it does require a little work. Speed as an issue should be attributed to the developer not the process - braiding results is pretty easy